# Web Deployment Projects for Visual studio 2005 download

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, microsoft-web-deploy

I'm trying to download Web Deployment Projects for Visual studio 2005 from Microsoft but i receive not found.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/c/b/ccb4877f-55f7-4478-8f16-e41886607a0e/WebDeploymentSetup.msi

The Help page is still active just not the download http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479568.aspx

Does anyone know where else i can download it from?

Thanks